# Remove indexes that are in nested field when deleting an object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm still on Firebase and this time I have a question related on the deletion of objects.

I have a structure like the following:

```
users: {
    UsErId1:{
        name: "Jack",
        email: "m@i.l"
    },
    UsErId2: { + },
    UsErId3: { + }
},
user_contacts: {
    UsErId1:{
        UsErId2: true,
        UsErId3: true
    },
    UsErId2: {
        UsErId1: true
    }
}
```

So if I want to delete an user I have to:

1. Delete the user object
2. Delete the user object under the user_contacts branch
3. Remove all the indexes from user_contacts that are pointing to that user

My performance problems comes from the point 3, because I need to iterate all the user_contacts entries to see if a user it's present in the childrens.

An example of code is the following:

```
private void deleteUser(String userId) {

    firebaseDatabase.getReference("users").child(userId).removeValue();
    firebaseDatabase.getReference("users_contacts").child(userId).removeValue();
    firebaseDatabase.getReference("users_contacts").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot usersSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for( DataSnapshot contactSnapshot : usersSnapshot.getChildren() ){
                    String contactId = contactSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    if( contactId.equals(userId) ){
                        contactSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

I've thought of two possible solutions:

- **Solution 1**: Don't delete the indexes from `user_contacts` and when I've to load the user contacts, I've to do a call to each user to see if the user is null (has been deleted), and in that case, don't show it. By the way, this results in a dirty database.
- **Solution 2**: create a reverse index `contacts_users` where I store the users for which the user I'm trying to delete is referenced. As follow:

  ```
  contacts_user: {
      UsErId1: {
          UsErId2: true
      },
      UsErId2: {
          UsErId1: true  
      },
      UsErId3: {
          UsErId1: true
      }
  }
  ```

So, when I have to delete a user, I will look at its childs in `contacts_users` and know every users that has it in its contacts, and proceed to delete it (now that I can know the entire path). This seems to me to be a more NoSql-like approach.

What do you think? Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second solution is how I would suggest doing it, no need to search. You could store that information on a per user basis, but if it grows too large having it elsewhere is better.

Likewise deleting in the other direction also becomes easier.

Comment: Same here: whenever you find yourself needing to loop+filter, you're likely better off creating a reverse index.