# How to check a firebase subnode for a specific value (UID)?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to query Firebase to check if the current user's uid is listed in a room's "participants". If so, I grab the info for that room.

Below is my current observer which listens to ALL rooms in the app, not just the rooms the user is a participant of. But I need to perform a check first, to see which rooms the current user's UID is listed in;  if there's a match (the uid is in a room's participants), THEN get the data for that room:

```
private func observeRooms() {

    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {print("Error getting user UID"); return}

    roomRefHandle = roomRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in

        let roomData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        let id = snapshot.key
        guard let name = roomData["roomName"] as! String! else {print("Error getting user name"); return}

        self.usersRooms.append(Room(id: id, name: name, participants: [uid]))

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

This is how the rooms are structured in the database:

```
"rooms" : {
    "-Ki6TJWO-2R1L4SyhSqn" : {
      "messages" : {
        "-Ki6TWrXxWqjaRJAbyVt" : {
          "senderId" : "tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53",
          "senderName" : "Timothy",
          "text" : "Room One message"
        }
      },
      "participants" : {
        "tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53" : true
      },
      "roomName" : "Room One"
    },
    "-Ki6TKOnmToeUuBzrnbb" : {
      "participants" : {
        "tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53" : true
      },
      "roomName" : "Room Two"
    },
    "-Ki6TLGC1Encm1v-CbHB" : {
      "participants" : {
        "tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53" : true
      },
      "roomName" : "Room Three"
    }
   }
```

How can I change my function so that it first checks all the room's participants for the current user's uid, before grabbing the values?

Thanks for any suggestions!

EDIT: Jay's approach:

```
private func observeRooms() {

    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {print("Error getting user UID"); return}
    let queryRef = roomRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "participants/\(uid)").queryEqual(toValue: true)

    queryRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        let roomDict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]

        let id = snapshot.key

        let roomName = roomDict["roomName"] as! String
        let participants = roomDict["participants"] as! [String: AnyObject]
        let numberOfParticipants = participants.count

        print("\nRoom Name: \(roomName)")
        print("Participants: \(participants)")
        print("Room ID: \(id)\n")

        self.usersRooms.append(Room(id: id, name: roomName, participants: [uid]))
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep it super simple, store a reference to the user in each room they belong to.

```
rooms
  room_0
   room_name: "My Room"
   users
    user_1: true
    user_2: true
  room_1
   room_name: "Their Room"
   users
    user_1: true
```

Then a simple query which will gather all the needed data, and will also leave an observer attached so if this user joins any new rooms the app will be notified.

```
let roomsUsersRef = self.ref.child("rooms")
let queryRef = roomsUsersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "users/user_1").queryEqual(toValue: true)

queryRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

    let roomDict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
    let roomName = roomDict["room_name"] as! String

    let usersDict = roomDict["users"] as! [String: AnyObject]
    let userCount = usersDict.count

    print("Room: \(roomName) has \(userCount) users")
})
```

and the output

```
Room: My Room has 2 users
Room: Their Room has 1 users
```

You could expand on this with .childChanged and .childRemoved to keep track of any events that occur in a room this user belongs to. So if another user joins or leaves a room this user is in, app will be notified; if the owner of the room boots this user from the room, the app will also be notified.

Comment: Admittedly this is difficult to test since right now I'm the only participant in all the rooms, and all the rooms only have me as a participant - but I got your suggestion working (see my question edit). I'm wondering though, does this only return the rooms that I'm (current user) a participant in? So I can now grab the data from only those rooms?

Comment: In your example, assume that you are `user_2` - will this only return `room_0`, since you are not in `room_1`?

Comment: @KingTim You are correct! Your question is *I'm trying to query Firebase to check if the current user's uid is listed in a room's "participants". If so, I grab the info for that room.* My solution does exactly that... and more! As it is, it will also notify the app if the user joins additional rooms; and with the addition of .childChanged and .childRemoved (or .value if it's a small number of rooms) it will notify you of any changes. Other users coming into the room or leaving, room name changes... even new posts!

Comment: Ok, I tinkered a bit and it seems to be working! I think my confusion was because I didn't realize you could simply query Firebase to filter out the rooms without the uid with `queryOrdered(byChild: "participants/\(uid)").queryEqual(toValue: true)`. I was trying to figure out how I would have to nest several observes.. first getting all the rooms, then observing that to get all the participants, then observing that to string match the UID. Really glad to see it's not that complicated. Jay, thanks so much for all your help, I imagine you wear a cape with the Firebase logo on it in real life.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally you would create a separate node in your app to store the information you want. Something like:

```
{
    "usersRooms": {
        "tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53": {
            "-Ki6TJWO-2R1L4SyhSqn": true,
            "-Ki6TKOnmToeUuBzrnbb": true,
            "-Ki6TLGC1Encm1v-CbHB": true
        }
    }
}
```

This would allow you to get the node for the user and instantly see what rooms they are apart of. Once you've done that you can loop over the results to get the individual rooms. In terms of keeping this list updated look into firebase functions or roll your own.

Comment: That's actually the way I had it before, another user here on SO recommended against this as it meant I would have each room twice in my database - for example if a user creates a new room, it would go into the user's rooms node, and also in the "global" list of all rooms in the app.

Comment: This would cause the app to have to read in that node and then iterate over all the child nodes to then read the information from each room. Really not very efficient and hard to maintain. Way better to just query the rooms for the rooms that the user is part of - that leaves and observer in place so if another user joins the room this user will be notified. If the room name changes they will be notified etc. And you only hit Firebase once to get all the needed data.

Comment: Not sure who told you against that @KingTim. Here's a comment from one of the firebase developers suggesting to create a reverse index: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39850117/remove-indexes-that-are-in-nested-field-when-deleting-an-object/39851107#comment66998223_39851107

Comment: @Jay here is a blog post about denormalizing where they discuss a similar issue with comments for a specific user instead of rooms: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html

Comment: @MathewBerg I told him that as in this use case denormalizing isn't needed as the structure is pretty flat to start with. It would cause unneeded, overlapping and nested queries to get the data. i.e. With your answer, once you have the room references, you then need to loop through all of them to capture the room names for example. On top of that, it doesn't leave observers ON the rooms to notify the client that something changed in the room - like a user leaving or entering the room.  I am all about denormalizing but it's dependent on the use case and depth of the structure.

Comment: @MathewBerg Oh, and thanks for that link - I've linked it numerous times to other users and it's really great information. However, at the time it was written, there were no deep queries and some other limitations as well. It's not quite as relevant now because in advancements in the API but still a very very good read.

Comment: I disagree with your assessment of the best way to approach this type of data structure. Long term if the room object expands it'd be better to flatten it out and denormalize it and your suggested answer would not be maintainable as it would cause unnecessary data being sent to the UI. For instance right now if I wanted to load a list of available rooms it would send me all the individual users that are in each room regardless of if I required that data or not. Unless I'm mistaken you would not be able to filter that out in a query and would ignore it in the client.

Comment: You are partially correct. However. Suppose the user is part of 50 rooms. With your solution; read in a list of 50 room refs. Now we want to get the room names. Loop over those 50 to get the room names /rooms/room_0/room_name, /rooms/room_1/room_name etc. But we also want to monitor changes in the rooms the user is part of. Now we have to add an observer to each of those 50 rooms as well. Adding that observer *reads in all of the child data for each room!* So in this use case denormalizing (the list) is a LOT more code and more difficult to maintain. See the super simple solution in my answer

Comment: Yep, it all depends on what your data will look like in the long run. Both have their benefits/drawbacks.